# Retrofit with UrlEncoded Object

Tags: android, retrofit

I could not find the correct information on this subject. The problem has already been mentioned, but there is no correct solution. No problem with request like:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/guide/confirm")
Call<Model> confirm(@Field("step") String step,  @Field("code") String code);
```

But, what is correct (!) way do encode all object, which has three or more list of other object. Parent and child object fields most converted with UrlEncoded.

```
// What need to do, to encode all data below?
@POST("/guide/loadinfo")
Call<Model> confirm(@Body VeryBigJsonObject object);
```

There was solution using TypedObject - but now is functions is deprecated, and it is not a new retrofit.  I hope you can help.

JakeWharton says in some issues, that my json is not url enoded form (its too large). That is mean, that I cannot send my request to server using Retrofit? Some example json: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=661b2bae9eb520902825a58f8d44c338

Answer (score 1):

I have so much troubles with sending whole class with form-urlencoded, because our server does not allow json.

I don't think it's correct way, but i dont find any better solution.
(i tried send my class by fields, but retrofit can't encode arrays in fields correctly)

After spending a lot of time, i did it like this:

```
public static RequestBody objectToRequestBody(Object obj)
{
    String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(obj);

    String reqestText = "";
    try {
        Object jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        reqestText = Tools.jsonToURLEncodingAux(jsonObj,"",0);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String mediaType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    return RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse(mediaType), reqestText);
}

public static String jsonToURLEncodingAux(Object json, String prefix, int level) {
    String output = "";
    if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)json;
        Iterator<String> keys1 = obj.keys();
        while (keys1.hasNext())
        {
            String currKey = keys1.next();
            String subPrefix = "";
            if(level>0) {
                subPrefix = prefix + "[" + currKey + "]";
            } else {
                subPrefix = prefix + currKey;
            }
            try {
                output += jsonToURLEncodingAux(obj.get(currKey), subPrefix, level + 1);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
        JSONArray jsonArr = (JSONArray) json;
        int arrLen = jsonArr.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
            String subPrefix = prefix + "[" + i + "]";
            Object child = null;
            try {
                child = jsonArr.get(i);
                output += jsonToURLEncodingAux(child, subPrefix, level + 1);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else {
        output = prefix + "=" + json.toString() + "&";
    }
    return output;
}
```

interface:

```
@Headers("Cache-Control: max-age=259200")
@POST("api/route/report/")
Observable<ReportResponsePOJO> sendReport(
        @Header("Content-Type") String content_type,
        @Body RequestBody report
);
```

and send it like this

```
Observable<ReportResponsePOJO> myResponsePOJOObservable = apiInterface
            .sendReport(
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    objectToRequestBody(report))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

I hope it will work, at least for me.

Comment: You saved me! Very hopeful.